# JWT Token (Invalid token Specified)

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I have module to check if the expiration date of token is already expired or not. so if ever the token is expired it will automatically the page will go to login again.

I already code it but their is error in my console and my page is loading anymore.

> Uncaught InvalidTokenError {message: "Invalid token specified"}

[image]

List not working

- I read some post it says need to put this. { header: true }
- Need specify if the localstorage has token

This is my code:

```
        if (localStorage.getItem("token") === null) {
        let token_expired = localStorage.getItem('token');
        let decoded = decode(token_expired, { header: true });
        let decode_string = decoded["exp"];
        var current_time = Date.now() / 1000;
        if(decode_string < current_time)
        {
            localStorage.clear();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that your token does not exist.

1. Go inside dev tools (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>) then
2. Select Application
3. Inside the Application go to Storage then
4. Open Local Storage (double click on local storage) then
5. Clear local storage

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to change the first condition, and use declarative names for variables.

```
const storedToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
if (storedToken){
   let decodedData = decode(storedToken, { header: true });
   let expirationDate = decodedData.exp;
    var current_time = Date.now() / 1000;
    if(expirationDate < current_time)
    {
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add **.token** to the token that I received from storage like this:

*Get token from storage*

1. const jwtToken = cookies.get("jwt_token");

*Give that token to jwtDevode as a parameter and add **.token** at the end*

2. const decodedToken = jwtDecode(jwtToken **.token** );

Answer (score 0):

This usually means your jwt has a bad format. Get your token in string, visit [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) and paste your token into it to see what's the body structure like and continue debug from there

Answer (score 0):

As Isaac has suggested, your jwt has a bad format hence throws the error preventing further execution of code. I suggest putting your logic in a try catch block like this:

```
 try {
    //what you are doing..
    if (localStorage.getItem('token') === null) {
      let token_expired = localStorage.getItem('token')
      let decoded = decode(token_expired, { header: true })
      let decode_string = decoded['exp']
      var current_time = Date.now() / 1000
      if (decode_string < current_time) {
        localStorage.clear()
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    localStorage.clear() //what you need to do incase the jwt is not valid
    console.log(e) //for your own debugging
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be a payload in Back-end it's just only a string, a number so it can't decode it out. I change back the payload in Back-end became an object and it worked.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMMwY.png)